# How to click on Button until a dependent value reaches a certain value?

Tags: javascript, protractor

With Protractor I'm trying to automate a part of a UI, in which with plus-minus buttons a min-max-range (i.e. 100'000-200'000) is selected.

There is an `inputAmount` (i.e. 250'000), defining the range to select.
Now I should click to the `plus-button` until I get a range 200'000-300'000, identified by the dynamically adjusted `<div class="currentMax">100'000</div>`.

My issue is to convert the `currentMax` of the currently selected range from String to a number, so I can compare it to the `inputAmount`.
The HTML looks like this:

```html
<html>
<div class="max">100'000</div>
<div class="slider-buttons">
  <div class="slider-button">
    <div class="slider-button-plus"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-button">
    <div class="slider-button-minus"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

My protractor code looks something like this:

```
this.selectAmountRange = function() {
    var currentMax = $('.max').getText();  //How do I get this value as number?
    var btnPlus = $('.slider-buttons .slider-button-plus');
    for (i = currentMax; i <= inputAmount; i = currentMax) {
        btnPlus.click();
        browser.wait(300);
    };
};
```

One problem is that `currentMax` is thousand-delimited with "'", so I can't convert it straight forward.
The other problem is, that getText() returns a promise, but even though I found some examples I failed so far to get the string and even remove the delimiter.

I tried this, but didn't work.

```
var currentMax = $('.max').getText().then(function(value){
    value.replace(/\'/,'');
    });
```

As I'm quite new to JavaScript and Protractor, I assume it's just some syntax I'm doing wrong.
Grateful for any advice and a nudge towards a doable function.

Comment: Have you looked up how to convert a string to number in javascript?

Comment: Yes, I did. However, I didn't come until that part as removig the ' was already a problem. I could solve that by making the passed argument an explicit String (else replace got interpreted as 'replace url', forcing the argument to be a location).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since javascript is asynchronous, you need to resolve the promise before accessing the return value from the promise. In your case, you need to implement recursion to make your method to click the slider until required value is set. Have a look at below example.

```
var selectAmountRange = function(inputAmount) {
     $('.max').getText().then(function(currentMax){
         var btnPlus = $('.slider-buttons .slider-button-plus');
          if(currentMax < selectAmountRange){
              btnPlus.click();
              browser.sleep(3000);
              selectAmountRange(inputAmount); //call the same method untill required inputAmount is selcted.
          }
     }; 
};
```

Comment: This answer is of great help for me!
Indeed the recursion solved most of my issue.
In your example, I had to remove 'var' and put a ')' at the end of the then-part. With that done I succeeded to repeatedly click the plus-button.
The part missing is 'how to convert my getText() into a number?'. It seems by default `currentMax.replace(/\'/,'')` is forcing my currentMax to be a location instead of a String (i.e. `100'000`).
Also strangely I get `null` from execution, but when I do `browser.enterRepl()` right at the beginning of then-function, the manual execution of the same steps work. Any clue?

Comment: Marked this as the right answer, since it solved my main issue (use `recursion` instead of `for`). But I'm still troubling with the getText-conversion, so I'm happy for further comments.

Comment: can you use the below regex `currentMax = parseInt(currentMax.repleace(/[^0-9]/g,''));`

Comment: It was the right hint. After all I had to enforce my function-input for currentMax to be a String, by using `getText().then(function(text){ var currentMax = parseInt(String(text).replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')); });`.
Now it finally works! Thanks again for the good input!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the right to comment so I put it as an answer, did you put all your code inside then() - after the promise returns the value ?

The currentMax is a variable initialized once, does the loop ends once it enters it !?

You mentioned currentMax and in code there is max are they the same ? what does the btnPlus click increments, the max ?

Finally I would suggest something similar to:

```
$('.max').getText().then(function(value){
    var currentMax = parseInt(value.replace(/\'/,''));
    var btnPlus = $('.slider-buttons .slider-button-plus');
    for (i = currentMax; i <= inputAmount; i++) {
        btnPlus.click();
        browser.wait(300);
    };
});
```

Comment: There are some good hints for me. I indeed needed to move some part into the `then()`. currentMax gets its value from div with `class="max"` so they're tight related, but not exactly the same.
In current case the increment is +100'000, but at other places its another amount. That's why I try to keep it as generic/reusable as possible.
Also I recognized from your question, that a `for`-construction doesn't work for me. The recursion as suggested by Sudharsan Selvaraj was, what worked.
From your example I can take the `parseInt`-part, but am still struggling (see my comment to Sudharsans answer)