# Protractor: Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm building Protractor tests for an Angular 4 app that some colleagues built.  Things are generally going well but I'm encountering the dreaded "stale element reference" error.

The periodically failing line of code is quite straightforward:

```html
expect(getElement('section.pipelines-container h6').getText()).toBe('PIPELINES')
```

It then calls this function I created:

```html
export function getElement(bySelector, timeout=5000) {
    var i = 0;
    var startTime = Date.now();

    if (typeof(bySelector) === 'string') {
        bySelector = by.css(bySelector);
    }

    try {
        do {
            driver.wait(until.elementLocated(bySelector), timeout)
                .then(e => driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(e)));

            if (element(bySelector).isDisplayed()) {
                break;
            }

            i++;
        } while (i < 3);
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log('Exception in e2e-utils.getElement: ' + ex.message)
    }

    if (i > 0) {
        console.log('Iterations: ' + i);
        console.log('Start: ' + startTime);
        console.log('End: ' + Date.now());
    }

    return element(bySelector);
}
```

I'm curious what more I can do to trap this error and try again to get the element?

Comment: Your test looks a lot like plain Selenium-Tests, kind of ignoring Protractors potential. If `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)` (default) and `ignoreSynchronization = false` (again default), then you shouldn't need this function as Protractor would wait for all tasks to be finished. So a plain `expect($('bySelector').getText()).toBe('PIPELINES')` should do it. Is there any reason for doing it the way it is? [About stale reference error in Selenium, read more here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I had already carefully read the link you provided.

I just tried your suggestion, adding the following before the set of tests:

   browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)
   browser.ignoreSynchronization = false

It didn't fix anything.  Then I added this:

                browser.sleep(5000)

It fixed it.  I was really trying to avoid introducing any explicit waits but it seems to be the only solution.

Comment: In this case, try to avoid the `do-while` instead. Use i.e. a recursion to re-call the `getElement` function until you find the element... this keeps it more synchronous. [Find an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46460912/8683679). The other thing I just recognized is, you could try using `browser.wait` instead of `driver.wait`. Driver diractly communicates with the browser and kind of bypasses the controlFlow.
Let me know, if one of the two helped.

Comment: Actually... after thinking twice it's most probably `driver` vs. `browser` as that way for a split-second you can get out-of-sync. It doesn't necessarily happen every time, but it can happen from time to time. I remember that I read about, but couldn't find the link on short hand.

Comment: Ernst, looking through my code, there was only one browser.driver. ... instance.  I removed the driver. portion and the code still runs.

With that said, I've spent way too much time trying to get Protractor working correctly.  I've added a `sleep` function which calls `browser.sleep`, `browser.waitforAngularEnabled`, and `browser.ignoreSynchronization` . I will call this function when code that should work is not working.  This strategy seems to be effective to get me working tests.

Comment: I'm having very similar issues, but just wanted to say that I think `browser.waitForAngularEnabled` only works for AngularJS? Could very well be wrong though.