# Protractor: Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document after click()

Tags: protractor, each

I am facing above issue when i am trying to click on the dropdown element which matches with given text. All the options of dropdown are as in the image with span having the text. 
I tried things given as in the link here,but no success. [Protractor: Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714460/protractor-failed-stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page?rq=1). Reference of tags are as given here in this pic below. [image: The tags used are <ul><li>.]

My code looks something like this

```
element.all(by.css('ul[class='ui-dropdown-items ui']>li')).each(function(element) {
  element.getText().then(function (text) {
     if (text.includes("Bag")){
       element.click();
     }
  });
});
```

Though the click action gets performed by above statement, still error is thrown.
Also when i try to click on any index as hard coded it works with no error.
element.all().get(4), where 4 being index of the element.
My application is in angular 5.
Can someone help me out on this! This is blocking my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element.all().each()` execute iteration on each element, even you add `if` condition to only click one element of all, But the `getText()` in each iteration still be executed.

After you click on the matched element,  the page redirected or refreshed.  Then call `getText()` on next element on "new" page, that's why report `stale reference exception`

You need to filter the matched element, then click on it.

```
// approach 1
element
.all(by.css('ul[class='ui-dropdown-items ui']>li'))
.filter(function(ele) {
  return ele.getText().then(function (text) {
     return text.includes("Bag");
  });
})
.then(function(eles){
    if (eles && eles.length > 0) {
        eles[0].click()
    } 
})

// approach 2
let options = element.all(by.css('ul[class='ui-dropdown-items ui']>li'))

options.getText(function(txts) {
  return txts.findIndex(function(txt){
    return txt.includes('Bag');
  })
})
.then(function(index){
    return index !== -1 && options.get(index).click();
})
```

Comment: Thank you Yong, it worked. But i am finding it difficult to convert this as promise. Because the function where i call this function is promise.

Comment: I tried first approach. but little modification i did, i took out the filter as another function.

Comment: function filter(allElements,testdata){
        var filteredEle = allElements.filter(function(ele) {              
            return ele.getText().then(function (text) {                    
                return text.includes(testdata);
            });
        })
        return filteredEle;
    }

Comment: var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();                                                             
var filteredArr = filter(elementAll,data.FIELD_VALUE);
        filteredArr.then(function(eles){
            if (eles && eles.length > 0) {
                eles[0].click().then(()=>{
                    deferred.fulfill();   
                },(err)=>{
                    deferred.reject(err);
                })
            }
            else{
                deferred.reject("filtered array has some issue!"); 
            } 
        })
        return deferred.promise;